# Will Uint32Array and other typed arrays already claim space when initialised?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typed-arrays, memory-consumption, typedarray

I'm trying to come up with an accurate measure of how much memory a particular datastructure will consume. Big part of that is ~ 1Million `Uint32Array` and 1M `BigUint64Array` both of max 200 elements.

Is my thinking correct that typed arrays that are initialised to a particular size already consume memory even without elements having been inserted, and that inserts don't change the amount of memory allocated?

If so, I can quickly get a sense of memory needed.

Comment: Yes. That's correct, at least with non-resizeable TypedArrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Constructing a new [typed array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) initialises it with a [buffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) of the respective size, which allocates the memory.

In theory, an engine could defer the allocation until the buffer is actually used to store values, but I haven't seen such an optimisation anywhere. It probably happens on the OS level anyway when paging the virtual memory.

Comment: *"In theory, [...]"*, could it? I believe they must allocate the DataBlock synchronously, otherwise they could lack memory afterwards and would fail to throw at construction.

Comment: @Kaiido I don't think that any language construct guarantees that you won't get an out-of-memory error later

Comment: The specs say that the memory must be allocated, so I guess it's a fair assumption that it throws only at constructs and not at use.